# Update table based on values in another table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sql-update

I have two tables I want to update table b in column `bcnt` by the value that in column `acnt` in table A where the worlds column in table A match words column in table B, and id in table B match id in table A.

```
create table a 
( 
    id number(9),
    words varchar2(2), 
    acnt number(9)
);

insert into a values(1,'Cairo',20);
insert into a values(1,'UK',10);
insert into a values(2,'KL',2);
insert into a values(2,'Cairo',2);
insert into a values(2,'London',30);
insert into a values(3,'Cairo',5);
insert into a values(4,'KSA',15);

create table b 
(
     id number(2), 
     words varchar2(20), 
     bcnt number
);

insert into b values(1,'Cairo',null);
insert into b values(1,'UK',null);
insert into b values(2,'KL',null);
insert into b  values(2,'Cairo',null);
insert into b values(3,'Cairo',null);
insert into b values(4,'KSA',null);
```

I used  this SQL code but it is not correct.

```
update b 
set bcnt = (select acnt 
            from a 
            where a.id = b.id and a.words = b.words);
```

Expected results:

```
1   cairo  20
1   uk     10
2    kl     2
2   cairo   5 
4   ksa     12
```

The SQL shows me the following

```
SQL> /

        ID WORDS                      BCNT
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Cairo
         1 UK                           10
         2 KL                            2
         2 Cairo
         3 Cairo
         4 KSA

6 rows selected.
```

SQL>

Comment: What is wrong with your SQL?  It looks ok to me.

Comment: (... except for the typos in column names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that your SQL uses `word` instead of `words` as in the table definition?

```
update b
    set bcnt=(select acnt from a where a.id=b.id and a.words=b.words );
```

Also, your data types are not correct in the two tables.  Your create table statements should be consistent:

```
create table a (id number(9),words varchar2(20), acnt number);
create table b (id number(9), words varchar2(20), bcnt number);
```

What is happening is that the values longer than 2 characters in the first table are being truncated to two characters.  So, instead of 'Cairo' the value is 'Ca' (to fit in varchar2(2)).  As a result, you have no match in the join.

Comment: Yes, you are right . but i get UK updated by 10 and KL by 2 that's fine But the OTHERS is EMPTY maybe updated by NULL Values.

Comment: i change it like this but also same only update two records( update b set bcnt=(select acnt from a where a.id=b.id and upper(trim(a.words))=upper(trim(b.words)) );